# Apache PIG questions

Tags: memory, mapreduce, apache-pig

I have few questions on running the pig script/ map-reduce jobs.

1. I know that pig creates **logical, physical and then execution plans** before it really starts executing the map/reduce job; I am able to look at the logical/physical plans using the command **explain <alias_name>**; But how do I view the execution plan (which I suppose list the different map/reduce tasks planned)? In the course of pig execution, I see that many jobs (map/reduce pair) are created. Want to understand what each of these jobs solve.
2. Is there any definitive guide which I can use to understand the plans created because what is spat is difficult to understand.
3. I am able to change the number of map jobs by changing the number of input file blocks. Do I have control over the number of reduce jobs as well? How do I set the number of reducers?
4. What is the default heap memory size in mapper/reducer nodes? Which job parameters reflect these? Will I be able to change the heap memory by **-Xmx 1024m** option? My jobs used to fail when I set the heap memory in this way - May be there are some restrictions on what values can be supplied?

Thanks much!

Answer (score 2):

1. There are different kinds of plans generated by explain. Give a directory path instead of a file to get all 3 plans from 'explain'.
2. No idea.
3. `set default_parallel 10` would set number of reduce jobs to 10.
4. It must be in your hadoop settings.

Comment: It's also worth noting that you can set the number of reducers for a particular operator in the statement itself. E.g. `B = GROUP A BY t PARALLEL 18;`

Answer (score 2):

1. "Explain(pig command )"  ALIAS-NAME explains the physical plan (in terms of Map reduce jobs)
2. Alias will be grouped together in a MR job . During the plan phase itself one can see , whicl all alias have been grouped into a given MR
3. To control number of reducer one can use "USING PARALLEL desired_no " when writing joins , groupby  or "set default_parallel desired no" at starting of pig script .
4. This depends on where is one running pig . 
   if its MRv1 : set mapred.java.opts -Xmx
   in mrv2 : set mapred.map.size , set mapred.map.java.opts -Xmx